# header to send chunked binary in Pyramid

Tags: python, streaming, pyramid

I have this view called dummy which I want to stream mp3 from my server and I wanna stream it to an `<audio src="/stream">` tag so clients can start immediately playing the file without waiting for the whole file.

```
def dummy(request):
    headers = {
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'binary',
        'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
        'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    }
    with open('songer.mp3') as handle:
        while True:
            bytes = handle.read(CHUNK)
            if not bytes:
                break
            return Response(bytes, headers=headers)
```

But I'm getting `ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING` from chrome, also I'm not sure if the way I return the response will work because wouldn't it end the response once it gets to the return?

Answer (score 5):

You're right, you can't return multiple responses from a view... or, in fact, generally issue multiple returns from a function in a loop - the first return statement will terminate the function.

Have a look at `Response.body_file` and `Response.app_iter` attributes.

> **response.app_iter:** 
>   An iterable (such as a list or generator) that will
>   produce the content of the response. This is also accessible as
>   response.body (a string), response.unicode_body (a unicode object,
>   informed by response.charset), and response.body_file (a file-like
>   object; writing to it appends to app_iter)
>
> **body_file** A file-like object that can be used to write to the body. If
>   you passed in a list app_iter, that app_iter will be modified by
>   writes.

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/response.html

If you do something like

```
request.response.body_file = open('songer.mp3')
# set any headers here
return response
```

the file will be read from disk and immediately sent to the client, without waiting for the whole file. I'm not sure if chunked transfer coding is necessary here.

WebOb documentation has an example of a more sophisticated file-serving app which can efficiently handle Range requests: http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/file-example.html

Comment: If your code above automatically handle streaming in bytes then that is what I'm looking for. I'll play around with it, Thanks

Comment: Sergey: thanks that works, but I'm faced in another problem. What if the whole mp3 has been read already an stored in a variable, do I just create and iterator and split the bytes into chunks and return it using yiel?

Comment: Yes, that would work. Or using StringIO to turn the variable into a file-like object and assigning it to Response.body_file. Although I'm not sure the above approaches will make any difference compared to just assigning your variable to Request.body. I mean, there's nothing special you need to do on the server to make client to play/display the file as soon as it gets a small part of it - that's how WWW works since the beginning. You just need to avoid reading whole large files into memory before serving them, that's what body_file and app_iter are for.